# How to merge two multi-indexed pandas dataframes?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, merge

Here are two pandas dataframes:

```
                          cq
Assay Time Repeat           
ACTB  0    1       22.000170
           2       21.882603
           3       22.064980
           4       21.838563
           5       22.089467


                          cq
Assay Time Repeat           
B2M   0    1       21.451027
           2       21.374013
           3       21.334360
           4       21.395817
           5       21.441243
```

How can I merge them to make it look like this:

```
                ACTB      B2M 
Time Repeat           
0    1       22.000170   21.451027
     2       21.882603   21.374013
     3       22.064980   21.334360
     4       21.838563   21.395817
     5       22.089467   21.441243
```

I've tried the `pandas.merge` function but no joy.

Answer (score 0):

I figured out the answer. We can use the `unstack` coupled to the `concat` functions

```
df_list= [i.unstack(level=0) for i in df_list]
print pandas.concat(df_list,axis=1)
```